# Is there an ace.js component available in Angular which can also work as FormControl

Tags: angular6

I am using `ace.js` in my project. The editor is part of a form field. However, the default `ace.js` implementation doesn't work as `FormControl` because it seem to use `div` instead of `textarea`. Is there an `ace.js` port which work well with `Angular` `Forms`? I suppose one way to solve the problem could be that I create a custom control which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. But if it is already done then it will save me quite some effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ng2-ace-editor` available at https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor